# Long file name overrides other items in statusline

Tags: neovim, statusline

I build my own statusline because I don't need such fancy things inside my statusline as some plug-ins provides. Usually everything is fine. The result looks like the following:

```
NORMAL   | ~/.config/nvim/lua/statusline.lua | +  | ft:LUA| buf:1| 1/123:23
```

But if I open a file with a deep nested path, my statusline swallows up my mode section. Like:

```
<ocal/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/zenburn.nvim/lua/zenburn/palette.lua/nvim/lua/statusline.lua | ft:LUA| buf:1| 1/123:23
```

This happens even if I put a minimal width on my mode section. Here is my function to create the statusline:

```
local function create_statusline(mapped_mode)
  local statusline_raw = {
    "%#", mapped_mode.hl, "#",
    " %7(", -- Breite des Mode (zusammen 9 Zeichen)
    mapped_mode.text, -- Mode
    "%) ", -- Schließt Mode-Teil
    "%*", -- Stellt eigentliche Highlightgroup wieder her
    " %F", -- Filename + Path
    " |", -- Separator
    " %.5(%M %R%)", -- Modifier +, ro
    "%=", -- rechte Seite
    " :%Y", -- FileType
    " ﬘:%n", -- BufferNr
    " %l/%L:%c", -- Line/line_count:column
  }         )
  return table.concat(statusline_raw)
end
```

The mapped_mode is a table with the text and a highlight group name as elements. The comments are a mix of German and English.

I think I don't understand the meaning of {minwid}. I hope some of you can help me out to get the mode section all the time in my statusline.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of options:

- use a `{maxwid}` to limit `%F` (like `%.50F`)
- don't use `%F` :)

FWIW, in my own statusline I have a "short" and "long" version.

```
function! s:status_line(verbosity) abort
  set statusline=
  if a:verbosity ==# 'long'
    set statusline+=%([%{Head()}%1*%t%*]%)
  elseif a:verbosity ==# 'short'
    set statusline+=%([%1*%t%*]%)
  endif
  set statusline+=%5*%(%m%r%w%h%)%*
  set statusline+=%(%y[%{&expandtab?'S':'T'}]%)
  set statusline+=%([%{exists('*FugitiveHead')?FugitiveHead():''}]%)
  set statusline+=%([%{get(w:,'quickfix_title','')}]%)
  set statusline+=%=%<
  if a:verbosity ==# 'long'
    set statusline+=%([%3*%l%*/%LL,%3*%c%*,%p%%]%)
    set statusline+=%([%{exists('*wordcount')?wordcount().words.'W':''}]%)
    set statusline+=%([%{&ff}\|%{(&fenc==''?&enc:&fenc).((exists('+bomb')&&&bomb)?'\|bom':'')}]%)
  elseif a:verbosity ==# 'short'
    set statusline+=%([%3*%l,%c%*]%)
  endif
  set statusline+=%(%a%)
  set statusline+=%4*%([%{AleCountTotal()}]%)%*
  set statusline+=%(%{exists('*ObsessionStatus')?ObsessionStatus():''}%)
endfunction

command SLLong call s:status_line('long')
command SLShort call s:status_line('short')

SLShort
```

You can ignore some of the functions. The interesting bit is that with long mode I show the full path, with the head and tail highlighted differently. In short mode I only show the tail (`%t`). I mostly use short mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> when I want to see the full path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I had the idea to limit the length of the file name by maxwid yesterday. I thought that this option was a little cheap but it works very well. I have to say that the solution with a long respectively short statusline is very tempting.

Comment: @grrr best say "thank you" with [votes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (though I'm consistently shocked that's a 15-rep privilege… here, have an upvote :) )